# Effective way of knowing if a dictionary has more than two of the same values

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, dictionary, nsmutabledictionary

I have a dictionary that contains events. The format for one event looks like this

```
{
   eventTime = 53';
   eventType = "Yellow Card";
   gameID = 0;
   name = Mike;
   selectedTeam = homeTeam;
}
```

And i have saved all of the events into an `NSMutableArray`. The clients will insert events as the time goes (for a soccer game). Now i need to check when populating my `UITableView` if a player has got two yellow cards so i can change the image to a different image. The way I'm doing it now looks like this and i don't really like it and it does not really work.

```
if ([typeEvent isEqualToString:@"Yellow Card"]){
    int i= 0;
    for (id obj in _events)
    {
        if ([[obj valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eventType"]] isEqualToString:@"Yellow Card"] && [[obj valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name"]] isEqualToString:[gameInfoObject valueForKeyPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"name"]]] ) {
            i++;
            if (i >= 2) {
                imageType = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow&Red.png"];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and in my UITableView i do this so you know what is what in the code above

```
NSMutableDictionary *gameInfoObject =[_events objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

So basically if there is more than 1 event in EVENTS array where the eventType equals "Yellow Card" and the name of those matches i need to change the image to "Yellow&Red"

Thank you for you help

Comment: Not really related to your question but: `[NSString stringWithFormat:@"StringWithNoFormattingSpecifiers"]` is just an expensive way to write `@"StringWithNoFormattingSpecifiers"`. Don't use `-valueForKeyPath:` with a path that you know only has one element. You could use `-valueForKey:`, but don't do that either when the key is hard-coded. For a dictionary, use `-objectForKey:`. For other objects, just invoke the getter for the property.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out! I got that i should change it to object for key but i didn't get how to implement @"StringWithNoFormattingSpecifiers". Example how would this line look?: [[obj objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eventType"]]
@KenThomases

Comment: [obj objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"eventType"]] can be written: obj[@"eventType"] in modern Objective-C

Comment: Is that way less expensive than the one i have? @dirkgroten

Comment: No, it's not a performance thing, the compiler will probably generate the same machine code in both cases. It's just much better readable and more consistent with other modern languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would start by using one of the fast enumerator methods provided by NSArray.

```
NSIndexSet *matchingSet = [_events indexesOfObjectsPassingTest:^BOOL(id obj,
                                  NSUInteger idx,
                                  BOOL *stop){
    return ([gameInfoObject[@"name"] isEqualToString:obj[@"name"] && [obj[@"eventType"] isEqualToString:@"Yellow Card"])
    }];

if (matchingSet.count >= 2) { 
     imageType = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow&Red.png"]; 
}
```

Comment: This answer stays closest to his original source.

Answer (score 0):

Look into using an NSCountedSet for your objects.  You'll get a constant time lookup and a count.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this in a few different ways. Personally, I think that having an event object is going to be the most readable for your code, but if you want to use simple objects like `NSArray` and `NSDictionary`, you could solve this easily with two extra `NSMutableArray`s or one extra `NSMutableDictionary` or one extra `NSCountedSet`.

`NSMutableSet`s:

```
NSMutableSet *yellowCardPlayers;
NSMutableSet *redCardPlayers;

- (void)receiveEvent:(NSDictionary *)event {
  [_events addObject:event];
  if ([event[@"eventType"] isEqualToString:@"Yellow Card"]) {
    if ([yellowCardPlayers containsObject:event[@"name"]]) {
      if ([redCardPlayers containsObject:event[@"name"]]) {
        // How did a player get a yellow card after already being ejected from the game?! :)
      } else {
        [redCardPlayers addObject:event[@"name"]];
      }
    } else {
      [yellowCardPlayers addObject:event[@"name"]];
    }
  }
}
```

`NSMutableDictionary`:

```
NSMutableDictionary *playerYellowCards;

- (void)receiveEvent:(NSDictionary *)event {
  [_events addObject:event];
  if ([event[@"eventType"] isEqualToString:@"Yellow Card"]) {
    NSNumber *numberOfYellowCards = [playerYellowCards objectForKey:event[@"name"]];
    if (![[playerYellowCards allKeys] containsObject:event[@"name"]]) {
      [playerYellowCards addObject:@(1) forKey:event[@"name"]];
    } else {
      [playerYellowCards addObject:@([playerYellowCards[event[@"name"]] integerValue]+1) forKey:event[@"name"]];
    }
  }
}
```

`NSCountedSet`:

```
NSCountedSet *playerYellowCards;

- (void)receiveEvent:(NSDictionary *)event {
  [_events addObject:event];
  if ([event[@"eventType"] isEqualToString:@"Yellow Card"]) {
    [playerYellowCards addObject:event[@"name"]];
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use NSPredicate to filter your array, and then count the results:

```
NSPredicate *yellowFlagFilter = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"eventType == %@ AND name == %@",@"Yellow Card", gameInfoObject.name];
NSArray *yellowCards = [_events filteredArrayUsingPredicate:yellowFlagFilter];
if ([yellowCards count] > 1) {
    imageType = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Yellow&Red.png"];
}
```